# Test datasource method issue using Mockito in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I have mocked the repository and datasource and created an object in the setup() method. This is my save new object method in the test class:

```
 public class RepositoryTest {

    @Mock
    private Repository repository;

    @Mock
    private DataSource mockDatasource;

    private Object object;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        mockDatasource = mock(DataSource.class);
        repository = Repository.getInstance(mockDatasource);
        object = new Object("Title", "Description", new ArrayList<SubObject>());
        when(repository.getObject(anyString())).thenReturn(object);

        when(repository.hasObject(any(Object.class))).thenReturn(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void saveObject() throws Exception {
        Object object = mock(Object.class);
         List<SubObject> subobjects = new ArrayList<SubObject>();
         subobjects(new SubObject("title1", "description1"));
         subobjects(new SubObject("title2", "description2"));
         object.setSubObjects(subobjects);

          /*
           * Instruct mockito to do nothing when datasource.saveSubObjects will be called.
           */
        doNothing().when(mockDatasource).saveObject(object);
        repository.saveObject(object);
        verify(mockDatasource, times(1)).saveObject(object);
        System.out.println("objects: " + repository.getObjects());

        //verify(mockDatasource).getObject(object.getId());
        assertTrue(repository.hasObject(object));
    }
}
```

This fails, I don't see the object when i call "repository.getObjects" and assert fails. I don't know if this called the save or not. Should i use doNothing() method? I have tested manually in app and it creates the new object. Just trying to make this from a unit test using Mockito and I am stuck. I am using ORM, not direct SQlite operations. I need a second opinion on this. Thank you.

Comment: could you show how you setup these mocks?

Comment: updated my code

Comment: add to your setUp `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` at first line if you want to use `@Mock` annotation, And you have to decide if you want to use `repository` object mocked with mockito or initialized by yourself in this line`repository = Repository.getInstance(mockDatasource);`

Answer (score 0):

If you mocked `repository` and did not specify what it should return when method `hasObjects` is called and if return type is bool it will by default return `false`.

Instead of checking if mocekd repository hasObject you should check if it has invoked methods responsible for saving this object.

```
public class Test {
    public boolean testMethod() {
        return true;
    }
}

....

Test mocekdTest = Mockito.mock(Test.class);
boolean b = mocekdTest.testMethod();
//b==false <-becouse by default mocked methods return false or null
```